# Hough Transform - sign of rho and theta- Matlab

Tags: matlab, sign, hough-transform

I understood that origin of the picture space (x,y) will be upper left corner.
Origin of the parameter space (rho, theta) will be center point.
I understood basic idea of the hough transform.

I am getting plots of Hough transform.

Range of Rho: `0` to `norm(max(x),max(y))`;

Range of theta: `-90` to `89`;

If **upper left corner** is origin in picture space [-y+x quadrant], where are the lines (on picture space) corresponding to the points `[1](rho=+90, theta=0), [2] (rho=-90, theta=0),
[3] (rho=5, theta=88), [4] (rho=5, theta=-88)` of the parameter space?

(My instinct tells me that the lines will surround the origin(upper left corner) and we should consider three more quadrant for +y+x, +y-x, and -y-x to contain points of the possible lines)

Can anyone explain graphically?

I want to know how MATLAB uses the sign to show the curves in parameter space.
Is it Clockwise from +x axis, theta will be `-ve` and Counterclockwise from +x axis, theta will be `+ve`?
Rho `+ve` for the 1st and 4th quadrant & `-ve` for the other two?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This site is for programming issues, your question might get more chances of being answered when posted on the signal processing site: dsp.stackexchange.com